# limit frame rate in jframe

Tags: java, jframe, cpu-usage

so im making a little text based adventure and it currently is eating about 45%-50% of my CPU because it is checking for your input continuously. So i need some kind of way to limit the framerate/update rate. when i try to put a thread.sleep(15) in to the loop that is checking the players input it stops doing anything with the input passed to it. ive seen similar questions but the answers given only apply to games that actually have a render method and as im using jtextareas and jtextfeilds i have no need for any kind of render method. Thus the solutions provided don't work for me. help?

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep completely pauses the current thread, when you use thread.sleep you prevent anything from happening in the thread. So no input is detected. Here is a game loop I modified to remove the render update part. Also while (true) methods are very laggy, and are generally not recommended.

You can call upon this loop when you want to activate it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    loop(0);
}

public static void loop(int looptype) {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double ns = 1000000000 / 60.0;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1) {

            if (looptype == 0) {
                *something*
                if (input.equals("1")) {
                    loop(1);
                } else if (input.equals("2")) {
                    loop(2);
                }
            } else if (looptype == 1) loop1(); 
            else if (looptype == 2) loop2();

            delta--;
        }
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
        }
    }
}

public static void loop1() {
*something*
}

public static void loop2() {
*something*
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is i dont have a method for repainting my jframe as im using jtextareas and jtextfeilds, im simply appending them as i go so i cant execute any kind of render method

Comment: I got rid of the render part, you should be able to put input code in the tick method. Does this fix it?

Comment: not exactly what i am doing is i have a jtextfeild that the player can enter an input to than i have a jbutton that writes this value to a variable as well as refreshing the players inventory and stats panel, and i just have a while loop checking the players input against a few values. i realize this is horribly inefficient which is why im here trying to get it to a at least manageable level, however it looks like i might have to do a whole system rewrite. OR i could tie the tic(); function into the submit action somehow? i dont know.

Comment: So its multithreaded? You start the jbutton & a loop that refreshes the inventory?

Comment: i just have the submit function as an action-listener idk if that creates a new thread.

Comment: It runs on a separate thread I believe, but shouldn't contribute to that massive CPU usage you see.

Comment: i believe the cpu usage is coming form my usage of a while(true) loop to check the input against the possible actions i just need to find a way to keep it from checking as often.

Comment: i just have while(true) loops inside while(true) loops ;-; i think im gonna have to rewrite my engine, or i could make it only check against the possibilitys when you submit an input? is there a way to wait until a variable => 0?

Comment: Didn't think a while loop inside a while loop would make a difference but updated it to include that

Comment: would that method limit it past the first decision made? because it looks like it would no longer limit the frame-rate after it goes into either the loop1 or loop2 methods.

Comment: It would absolutely limit the tickrate, the framerate however depends on your program. It will reduce CPU usage regardlessly. It calls upon loop1 + 2 depending on your system time. Only getting called 60 times a second rather then as much as possible with the while(true) loop.

Comment: Basically yes, it would use less cpu.

Comment: hmmm, i see no improvement when using your method, ill work on this in the morning, but for now im gonna go to sleep. thanks for the help!